# PHP - check if a variable is set then print it in one command

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP shorthand for: print var if var exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836515/what-is-the-php-shorthand-for-print-var-if-var-exist)

In order to print a variable, I'm doing this:

```
if(isset($var)) print $var;
```

But Im repeating $var 2 times here. Is there a way to make it look like:

```
If $var exists then print it
```

instead of

```
If $var exists then print $var
```

Comment: what's the problem if you call the variable again?

Comment: There is no problem, i'm just looking for a way to improve my code (if there is).
It follow the same thinking as when for an example I learned that I can do: <?= $var ?> instead of <?php echo $var ?>..

Comment: There's no need to shorten that, shorter is'nt always better. As a sidenote, shorttags are not always a good idea either, as they are disabled by default in some versions of PHP.

Comment: echo ($var) ? $var : "";

Comment: @SureshKamrushi : that will not make an isset on the variable. if variable doesn't exist , will throw error.

Comment: Yes @Zaffy, I could use a custom function, but it wouldn't be better than the if statement Im avoiding..

Well, Im not desperate on this, if there isn't a way then there isn't a way, I'm just looking out of curiosity

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`print (isset($var) ? $var : '');`

`?:` called [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: here also $var repeating;

Comment: yeah, but I would access $var 2 times.
What I'm looking for is like a function or a way to write: `If_this_variable_exists_then_print_it($var);`

Comment: @vladimire There is no way of doing that, short of writing such as function yourself. That is just how the language works; it is much easier to just accept the language for what it is.

Comment: Actually there are no way to do anything with undefined variable in a function like in comment. It will print a notice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `$var` to the empty string so you will not need the if-check.

Assuming that you do `$var = $_REQUEST['var'];`, you'll be out of luck.

Imho it is a micro-optimisation, not really important.

Answer (score 0):

Use the help of Error Control Operator "@" http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

```
echo @$var;
```

I don't think to use "If $var exists then print it" is faster than "If $var exists then print $var". Internally the script-engine to check the variable is set or not. May be it is micro-optimization.

This type questions may be asked in IT-Quizzes.
I remember one question "how to write a program which print a string. The condition is that don't use semicolon". Answer is given.

```
<?php if(print("Hello World")){}
```

Comment: **No.**  Never ever intentionally use the silence operator.  *Ever!*

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no short and PHP built-in solution for this.

In our framework we use our own function:

```
function isset_(&$aVariable, $aDefaultValue = null)
{
    if (isset($aVariable)) return $aVariable;
    return $aDefaultValue;
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
echo isset_($var);
```

Comment: double under-score is usually used in PHP-magic functions. Better not to use in user-defined functions. "__isset" is also a magic function.

Comment: @habeebperwad Thanks. Function name has been changed. But logic stays the same.

Answer (score -2):

You could do `<?php echo @$var; ?>. Or <?= @$var ?>.`

Comment: **No.**  Never ever intentionally use the silence operator.  *Ever!*